# Wherenull query doesn't return anything from pivot table (laravel5.5)

Tags: laravel

I have crime_criminal table that has this

[image]

With regards to that this is my CrimeCriminalSeeder

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\CrimeCriminal ;
class CrimeCriminalSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
// seeding criminal_description table..
        $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();

        $crimes = CrimeCriminal::whereNull('crime_description')->get();


        dd($crimes);
    }
}
```

but I get like this in my terminal

[image]

Comment: try using `toSql()` function instead of `get()` on `$crimes`, It will give the query output, which you can try running on database console.

Comment: Yeah Definitely I get "select * from `crime_criminal` where `crime_description` is null" in the console

Comment: And you are getting the results for the same query on database console?
sorry, but I'm just rechecking.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially the column stating (null) may contain text? Otherwise seems correct.